# Prepared statement with ? AS `name`

Tags: mysql

I'd like to use a prepared statement like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
z.`number`,
z.`name`
FROM (
    SELECT 
    ? AS `number`,         <<<<<<<< THIS LINE FAILS
    `name`
    FROM `plu` AS p
    WHERE p.id=?    
) 
AS z
```

Sadly, it gives an error when preparing: **Unknown column 'number' in 'field list'**.

If I replace the `?` with actual numbers and execute it manually, it works fine.

So, my question, is it even possible to us `? AS name` in a prepared statement?

Comment: You can't parameterize field names and table names. Generally this is the result of poor table design/schema.

Comment: Try `? AS number` (not backticks)

Comment: No luck without the backtics

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You can't parameterize field names and table names.

Comment: @JNevill Is he trying to do that?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This is a duplicate, for sure, but not because of the lack of backticks.

Comment: My excuses, MySQL does indeed allow to quote aliases with absolutely any kind of quote characters.

Comment: You cannot parameterize table names or column names. The reason being that the database cannot compile a query if it does not know in advance the table and column names that are involved in the query

Comment: I am amazed that I cannot find a DUP for this question that I am sure I have seen many times before

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've been looking for an answer for some time, before asking the question here. Couldn't find it either.

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? What client or library are you using? What exactly code? I see nothing wrong in it and it run flawlessly in PHP using the PDO library.